# pythonic way to decorate a generator at run-time?

Tags: python, design-patterns, iterator

I have the following code:

```py
def assertfilter(iterator, predicate):
    # TODO support send()
    for result in iterator:
        if not predicate(result):
            raise AssertionError("predicate failed in assertfilter()")
        yield result
```

Any attempt *I* could come up with to refactor it to support `send()` seems to look horrifically convoluted, unreadable, and non-obvious:

```py
def assertfilter(iterator, predicate):
    result = None
    while True:
        try:
            sent = yield result
            if sent is not None:
                result = iterator.send(sent)
            else:
                result = next(iterator)
            if not predicate(result):
                raise AssertionError("predicate failed in assertfilter()")
        except StopIteration as e:
            if e.value is not None:
                return e.value
            return
```

Is there a recognized, common, readable way to inject/wrap logic onto an existing generator that doesn't fail on edge cases?

Comment: Iterators don't support `send`; *generators* do. Your second attempt is much more complicated because you are no longer restricting yourself to the simpler iterator protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fighting the tangled logic of generator semantics and maybe missing edge cases (what if the generator's already started, for example? Is it even possible to handle that robustly, transparently, and generalizably from an approach like that in the question?), one possible solution is writing a class:

```py
class _WrappedGenerator:
    def __init__(self, generator, function_out=None, function_in=None, force_wrap_input=False):
        self.__wrapped__ = generator
        self._function_out = function_out if function_out is not None else lambda x: x
        self._function_in = function_in if function_in is not None else lambda x: x
        self._force_wrap_input = force_wrap_input
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self, *a, **k):
        try:
            if self._force_wrap_input:
                return self.send(None)
            return self._function_out(self.__wrapped__.__next__())
        except StopIteration:
            if a:
                return a[0]
            if 'default' in k:
                return k['default']
            raise
    def send(self, value):
        return self._function_out(self.__wrapped__.send(self._function_in(value)))
    def throw(self, *a, **k):
        return self.__wrapped__.throw(*a, **k)
    def close(self):
        return self.__wrapped__.close()
```

arguably overkill, but I think it'll work perfectly and handle all the edge cases.